# Force update in InitializeComponent

Tags: vb.net, designer, vb6-migration

I'm deveoloping in VB.Net and I'm making batch modification to Designer.vb file. My new code compiles, but there are some modification that does not apply until I open the Designer.vb in Design mode in the VS.
When I open it in VS, the Windows Form Designer rewrite InitializeComponent and the Designer works fine.

Is there any way I can make a batch to force the Windows Form Designer to "rebuild" or "update" my new code, so it's get ok?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "batch modification" are two very scary words.  VS has no reason to assume that anything changed behind its back when the form is opened in the designer.  You must close the designer first to avoid accidents.

Comment: Please verify the steps. 1) External to VS, the <form>.designer.vb file is modified. 2) the modified code compiles; however, the executable does not appear as desired. 3) You open the project in VS and open the form in design view. 4) the form designer updates the <form>.designer.vb file such that when compiled the executable appears as wanted. If this is accurate, then I suspect that you are adding a component to the InitializeComponent method but are not including the all the initialization code added by its CodeDomSerializer. Figure out the missing statements and add them to step 1.

Comment: If the pattern of what it changes inInitializeComponent is consistent, you could / should try to manually replicate this. Also, I would be sure to use source control between each revision to these files to save trouble if/when things go wrong!